# Permission issue in tomcat VM

Tags: tomcat, permissions

We've been running tomcat servers in 3 Google VMs for about a year.  The other day we updated our WAR program in tomcat, and suddenly it seems that permissions for our web app's folder and subfolders have changed.  Whereas we used to be able to SSH into the server and see our webapp, its files, and its subfolders from the command prompt, they are all now invisible.

The webapp is still running and it self reports that it's at the same, expected path.  But we're unable to see it under the /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps folder, which is where it should be (and apparently is).

Parts of the program need to create temporary files in subfolders, and these subfolders are either non-existent or not writeable.  But we have no command line access to these now.